# How to sort a copy of a C++ vector depending on position of elements in the original vector?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I do have this map in my class :

```
map<string,vector<pair<string,int>>> assessedTest__name_result;
```

And I have copied the vector to another, temporary one, which I would like to sort by the first value in the pair. In case there are two elements with the same first value in the pair I would like to determine the position by their position in the original vector. But I if I want to look at the original vector the static vector sorting function won't allow me to do that. Could you please tell me how to do it ?
Thanks

The code :

```
//test is the key in the map shown above
vector<pair<int,int>> tmpVec = assessedTest__name_result.at(test);
sort (tmpVec.begin(),tmpVec.end(),vecIdSort);
...
bool myClass::vecNameSort(const pair<string,int>& firstElem, const pair<string,int>& secondElem, const string& test){
    if (firstElem.first < secondElem.first)
        return true;
    if (firstElem.first > secondElem.first)
        return false;
    return AssSort(firstElem.first, secondElem.first,test); //in case the elements are the same
}

bool myClass::AssSort (const int firstId, const int secId,const string& test){
    bool foundFirst,foundSecond;
    vector<pair<string,int>>::iterator first,second;
    for (auto it = assessedTest__name_result.at(test).begin();it != assessedTest__name_result.at(test).end(); it++){
        if ((*it).first == firstId){
            first = it;
            foundFirst = true;
        }
        if ((*it).first == secId){
            second = it;
            foundSecond = true;
        }
        if (foundFirst && foundSecond) break;
    }
    return first < second;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

std::stable_sort is the answer

```
std::stable_sort(tmpVec.begin(),tmpVec.end())
```

If you have your own comparison function `vecIdSort` do this

```
std::stable_sort (tmpVec.begin(),tmpVec.end(),vecIdSort);
```

Comment: just like that ? only use stable_sort instead of sort ?

Comment: @Jesse_Pinkman if you have a different comparison  function, please pass it as third argument similar to sort

Comment: actually it is more complex that I have said here - I do have another map of <int,string> in which I have ID to name conversion and in the array to be sorted I only have the ID number - which cannot repeat and in the sorting I have to convert the ID to name everytime - and the names can be repeated. Do you have any idea how to do this ?

Comment: See `std::map<int,string>` is sorted in default with key as id. So do you really need to sort again using a `std::vector<>`. If names can be repeated, use `std::multimap<int,string>`, it will sorted with key in default.

Comment: yes, I do need to sort it again since map<int,string> is a map of student ID's connected to their names and map<string,vector<pair<string,int>>> is a map of tests, with vectors of pairs of student ID's and their results - they are pushed back in order of their assessment and I want to sort the map of results by student names and in case the names are the same I want to decide with their position in the map of assessed test. And I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score -2):

I used a lambda function and it worked.

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer

Comment: Well because I needed to look into other arrays as well I had to use the lambda function - with stable sort. Should I post the code of how I did it ?

Comment: Adding your full solution with a bit of sample code will help others solve similar problems in the future.